# Android - Custom SSL certificate chain checking without bundling keystore with the app

Tags: android, ssl, x509certificate

I am after a solution which would enable me to use the in-build keystore and StrictHostnameVerifier but would allow me to obtain the X590CertificateChain (either once connected or post handshake) so I can perform some additional checks (specifically I want to verify the root public key is the one I expected).

The examples I have investigated are mainly around overriding the behaviour (i.e. by replacing the socket factory or hostname checker with ones which don't do anything) and I am struggling with the differences between the android and other java implementations.

The reason I don't want to bundle a keystore (aside from having to use bouncycastle instead of jks) is that I don't want to package the intermediate CA cert with the app as this will create a certificate management problem sooner.

Many thanks in advance for any comments.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, this should be done at runtime. Bundling the certificate might be redundant as well, when some devices might already have that certificate installed.

Normally, your approach should be this.

1. Try connecting to the server.
2. If certificate is not installed, you will get a certificate exception. Catch it, extract the public certificate, save it, by creating a keystore on the fly.
3. While making new connections, use this keystore to initialize your SSL context.

Comment: Thanks Kumar - I have attempted this approach using an empty keystore (I don't want to trust all of the hundereds of CAs) however I was unable to obtain the certificate from the SSLException, HTTPGet or the Client. If I add a keystore resource with the root+intermediate, I am still faced with an SSLException for Not Trusted Server Certificate: